# emacs function behaves differently when bound to keymap

Tags: emacs, elisp

New to elisp and need help.

I have a simple function that pages down docview when the frame is split into two windows:

```
(defun noteview-pagedown ()
  (interactive)
  (with-selected-window (other-window-for-scrolling)
    (doc-view-scroll-up-or-next-page nil)))

(defconst noteview-mode-keys
  '(("C-M-v" . noteview-pagedown)))

; lifted from android-mode.el
(defvar noteview-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(add-hook 'noteview-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (dolist (spec noteview-mode-keys)
              (define-key
                noteview-mode-map
                (read-kbd-macro (concat noteview-mode-key-prefix " " (car spec)))
                (cdr spec)))))
```

Left window has a text doc with this function defined. Right window has a pdf with docview open.

When I press C-M-v it runs correctly the first time then incorrectly the second time. It seems to do a page-down then a page-up alternately so I never progress to the next page.

When I run this function interactively with M-x noteview-pagedown it works.

Any hints on why this won't work from a keyboard macro would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `C-h k C-M-v` after you run the above code? Also, is `noteview-mode-key-prefix` defined somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a

> noteview-mode-map

, but no

> noteview-mode

.  I'm unconvinced that this dangling map can ever do anything, unless you've defined the minor-mode else where.

This shouldn't be a minor-mode in any case, you appear to want to make C-M-v scroll other window, even when it's showing a doc-view buffer?

```
(defun my-scroll-up (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (with-selected-window (other-window-for-scrolling)
    (if (eq 'doc-view-mode major-mode)
        (doc-view-scroll-up-or-next-page arg)
      (scroll-up arg))))

(define-key (current-global-map) [remap scroll-up] 'my-scroll-up)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about doc-view, but I just did `C-h f doc-view-scroll-up-or-next-page`, and it seems to say that in order for it to move to the next page you must have non-nil `doc-view-continuous`.  Is that the case?  Here's the doc:

```
Scroll page up ARG lines if possible, else goto next page.
When `doc-view-continuous' is non-nil, scrolling upward
at the bottom edge of the page moves to the next page.
Otherwise, goto next page only on typing SPC (ARG is nil).
```

HTH.